# signaler not working (aurelia)

Tags: aurelia

I am using the RC.
Signaling was working (i use it alot) but then suddenly it stopped and i don't find why.

you see in this code this.signals is quite empty and doesn't contain my name "machines-fetched" (it has some values from translations

```
  BindingSignaler.prototype.signal = function signal(name) {
    var bindings = this.signals[name];
    if (!bindings) {
      return;
    }
    var i = bindings.length;
    while (i--) {
      bindings[i].call(_aureliaBinding.sourceContext);
    }
  };
```

It only contains some value from translation signal.
[image]

Greetings
Felix

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the 1.0 release?

Comment: Yes i tried and got many errors (related to aurelia-breeze) that i tried hours to solve so eventually i reverted

Comment: It's quite possible that there's some mismatching of node_modules happening (I'd bet that's the problem). You might be able to specify exactly the version you want for all the packages with something like shrink-wrap. But your best bet is to clean your node modules, and get the latest for them all. Your breeze problem might be something else that needs to be solved. Curious, what is the breeze problem?

Comment: thanks, i don't remember the breeze error but i lost many hours investigating it and got several error's in a row. It was a nightmare. I'm thinking abandoning aurelia and breeze and only use Typescript so i know exactly what happens because i got alot of problems the last 1.5 years. I just like the templating/composition stuff, don't know which framework is very light (aurelia is heavy) and easy that offers this. 
I didn't update the packages in package.json, so it's not that. How can i check where the DOM is scanned to find 'signals'?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with "signals", so I'm not much help there. Truly, once you get into Aurelia, it's a nice framework to be in. If you're on gitter, there's a channel for aurelia which is quite helpful. And if you're on over there, you can message me at AStoker, and I'll be happy to help you get up and running.

Comment: Sometimes, errors can trickle down, and so your breeze issue might have been something higher up that needs to be fixed. Let me know if you want any help getting that solved.

Comment: thanks Andrew, i texted you on gitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that i added some piece of code with invalid If.bind that caused the signaling from not working anymore:

```
 <span class="badge" if.bind="">
        <a  click.trigger="totop()">
           <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:1.2em">&#xE5CE;</i>
        </a>
 </span>
```

Removing the if.bind="" (or adding a proper variable inside) fixed the problem